# ASP.net MVC Sharing methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, methods

I have two methods that use different viewmodels but are the same logic. At the moment I have copied and pasted them into their respective controllers. Any way to share these methods somehow?

Song Controller:

```
public JsonResult IncrementViews(int id)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            PublishedSongViewModel song = db.PublishedSongs.Single(x => x.Id == id);
            song.UniquePlayCounts++;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { UniquePlayCounts = song.UniquePlayCounts }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Station Controller:

```
public JsonResult IncrementViews(int id)
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                RadioStationViewModel station = db.RadioStations.Single(x => x.Id == id);
                station.UniquePlayCounts++;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { UniquePlayCounts = station.UniquePlayCounts }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Edit:
class so far:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetElements(ApplicationDbContext db, Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(SongsController))
            return (IEnumerable<Type>)db.PublishedSongs;
        else if (type == typeof(RadioStationsController))
            return (IEnumerable<Type>)db.RadioStations;
        else
            throw new Exception("Controller not found, DBHelper");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a class called `BasicController` and add the method to it, like this:

```
public class BasicController {
    public JsonResult IncrementViews(int id)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var element = DBHelper.GetElements(db, this.GetType()).Single(x => x.Id == id);
            element.UniquePlayCounts++;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { UniquePlayCounts = song.UniquePlayCounts }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

and modify your classes to inherit from `BasicController`. You will also have to create the `DBHelper` class with the `GetElements` method, which gathers the `IEnumerable` elements from db based on type.

EDIT: This is how you can create a helper:

```
public class DBHelper {
    public static IEnumerable GetElements(ApplicationDbContext db, System.Type type) {
        if (type == typeof(SongController)) {
            return db.PublishedSongs;
        } else if (type == typeof(StationController)) {
            return db.RadioStations;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I create the GetElements method. I have never done helpers before really so I don't know where to start?

Comment: You need to create a class called DBHelper, like you create any other class. Inside that you need to define GetElements which will receive an application db context and a System.Type. Based on System.Type you gather the elements. You need to use if-elses for that purpose.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson, please check my edit. It is untested code, so if something does not feel quite right, then please add a comment

Comment: <T> was undefined so I changed it to Type, not sure if this is correct or not.

Also in my controller `x.Id` cannot be found on `this.GetType()).Single(x => x.Id == id)` It has GUID as a property but I am using int Id

Comment: Maybe try without <T> if C# accepts it. I have no environment for C# right now. The second problem is that you tried to do it with Type.